# Fixed Scale / Fixed Zoom in eCognition

Tags: scale, trimble, ecognition

I'm wondering if there is any option in eCognition Developer / Architect were I can control Zoom or Scale Factors. It's necessary for my work that I use the same scale for all processing steps.

Answer (score 3):

Please use the 'set custom view settings' in eCognition 8.9 to set/control the zoom via a rule set.